# Android Facebook Login - Access Token purpose

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm implementing Facebook Login in Android, and I actually have it working, but I'm wondering if I need to worry about the access token that is associated with the session at all. I'm using this tutorial and it doesn't mention using the access token at all:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0

I know internally, the Facebook APIs will all use that access token when I make Facebook calls, but should I be worrying about the access token outside of this context?

I know it can be accessed like this:

```
session.getAccessToken();
```

For example, can I use the access tokens to uniquely identify users in my app? In my app, when a user logins via Facebook, I store their info in my database essentially making them a user of my app. Whenever the user does something in my app that requires a server call, I'm passing in the facebookId. I feel like this could easily be spoofed by someone who wants access to another users info though. Would storing the current access token fix this problem?

Comment: Of course, you can use it for identify the user in server. But the token includes information about when the token will expire and which app generated the token. so you have to check the time when it will be expire, if it expire, you shud login facebook again to get new token. I hope it to be helpful for you. refs [facebook token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

Comment: I still see a potential securityu flaw though, but maybe I'm just over thinking it. In order to associate that user with an access token in the server you'd have to send the access token and the userId/facebookId to the server together. If someone was savy and they were able to grab the request, and modify it, they could put the facebookId/userId of the user's who's information they want into the request and all of a sudden they know the user's access token. Now every call to my server that requires the facebookId and access token is compromised.

Comment: when user sign up the your app, you can save their info(like facebook user info, etc). and when they login, what about using the session id for login? make server only can access the user info directly. you don't need to include them whenever every call.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean with the session id? In my app I have lots of things like private messages, followers, etc and they all are stored in a database by the user (user in the context of my app) id that is generated when the facebook user logs in for the first time. In order to get new private messages and such the app needs to make a call like myapp.com/get/messages and attach the userId as a POST param. Without have a password because this is a facebook user, I don't see how it's possible to verify that the request is not tampered with. Anyone could make the call from a browser

Comment: If you only make request to FB from your mobile app, then there's no need to keep a record of the access token on your server. You should use the user ID that FB gives you to uniquely identify the user. As for your security concerns, you should have your own access tokens/session ids when your app communicates with your server (over https), in order to mitigate spoofing.

Comment: As for my security concerns I'm thinking the best way to solve it will be to get an access token on the FB session when the user logs in or enters the app, and then when he/she makes remote calls I send that access token to my PHP backend which will then query the facebook graph api with something like: https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN.

That way I'll know if the access token is valid then I have a legit facebook user.